# How to show progress in the separate form in winforms app?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am writing winforms app in C#. In one of the forms there is a functionality to upload file to the remote http server. How can I show progress in different form making both forms responsive to user actions.
Here is my method for uploading file:

```
private void UploadTestFile()
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_url);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_loginName, _password);
        Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead("test.exe");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        double fileStreamLength = (double)fileStream.Length;
        int byteRead = 0;
        double read = 0;
        do
        {
            byteRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
            ftpStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteRead);
            read += (double)byteRead;
            int progress = (int)(read / fileStreamLength);
        }
        while (byteRead != 0);
        fileStream.Close();
        ftpStream.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UploadFileAsync`

```
WebClient Uploader = new WebClient();
```

then in the Constructor you can create this events

```
Uploader.UploadFileCompleted += UploadFileCompletedCallback;
Uploader.UploadProgressChanged += UploadProgressCallback;
```

and while the Uploader is progressing it would fire the event

```
private void UploadProgressCallback(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => {
        //Send the values to another form e.ProgressPercentage or e.BytesSent 
            }));
}
```

at the completion of Upload

```
private void UploadFileCompletedCallback(object sender, UploadFileCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
            {
                //Tell another window or form that File Uploaded.
            }));
}
```

To call this

```
private void UploadTestFile()
{
     new Thread(() => Uploader.UploadFileAsync(new Uri("http://YourURI.com/toUpload"), "POST", "test.exe").Start();
}
```

Comment: I tried this code, but it doesn't upload file. It just shows progress form and immediately closes it. And what about credentials?